# AFNetworking - POST file progress random stuck

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, rest, afnetworking

I'm using **AFNetworking** and **AFJSONRequestOperation** to post an image along with some parameters to my REST server with this code.

```
NSData* uploadFile = nil;
if ([params objectForKey:@"file"]) {
    uploadFile = (NSData*)[params objectForKey:@"file"];
    [params removeObjectForKey:@"file"];
}

NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path:kAPIPath
                          parameters:params
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
               if (uploadFile) {
                   [formData appendPartWithFileData:uploadFile
                                               name:@"file"
                                           fileName:@"photo.jpg"
                                           mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                   [formData throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:5000 delay:kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedDelay];

               }
           }];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2 = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
[operation2 setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2, id responseObject) {
    //success!
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2, NSError *error) {
    //failure :(
    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
}];
[operation2 setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    if (self.delegate) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        [self.delegate didReceiveData:(totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)];
    }
}];

[[API sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation2];
```

This works randomly. I mean some times everything works perfectly and some times the progression get stucked in the middle of the sending process and finish with a Timeout error.

I tried with tons of parameters and different combinations but I have always the same behavior.

**PS : I use the last version of the Framework.**

***PS2 : All my tests are made on both simulator and device, and also over a Wifi connection***

Answer (score 0):

> This works randomly. I mean some times everything works perfectly and some times the progression get stucked in the middle of the sending process and finish with a Timeout error.

This is a server-side issue, then. Depending on what kind of endpoint your uploading to, you may need to [throttle the data rate of the upload](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize%3adelay%3a).

Comment: I've tried to add the method but the size of the packets doesn't change from what I can see in the log of the ProgressBlock and if I add a delay this cause a disconnection from the server.

All my tests are made from the simulator and a phone and always over a Wifi connection.

Also I just wanted to add that I never saw the "request body stream exhausted" error in my failureBlock.

Comment: Well that narrows down the possibilities a little. It's really hard to say one way or another. It's most likely a server issue, so as much as you are able to, you should focus debugging efforts there.